# How to backspace the characters in the cmd buffer?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-xp, windows-vista, cmd.exe

If we use command prompt to run short scripts as such:

```
C:\php> php.exe

<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```

, the output would be displayed directly in the command prompt:

```
test
^C
C:\php>
```

So let's say there are typo errors and I'd like to do a "backspace".

E.g. assuming we mistyped `echo` as `echoo`:

```
C:\php> php.exe

<?php
echoo 'test';
```

How can I achieve "backspace" behavior on cmd without having to abort the full script and retype everything from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMD does support the backspace key, and it does work as you describe when you're typing a command *before* executing it.

Once you've begun the command (php.exe in this case) then [STDIN](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/stdin.htm) is attached to that program (not CMD) and therefore it's up to that program whether it implements or allows backspacing or not.

To the program, the backspace key is just another character that it needs to process (e.g. [ASCII #8](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/backspace-ascii-code-8.html)).

Comment: (For apps that do not implement this feature) In other words, are you saying that it's not possible to "hack" around this limitation?

Comment: Once you've executed the app, no. However for PHP, you could try this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Comment: Ah, was thinking some sort of "standard" protocol would have been built by now to tackle this annoying issue....

Comment: @Pacerier : Nope: The keyboard buffer was supported by the old BIOS systems from way back in the pre-486 days.  It was limited to 16 keystrokes, I think.  Pressing backspace would use up another one of those 16 remembered keystrokes, not remove one.  Nowadays technology may have advanced; maybe operating systems support unlimited buffers these days, I don't know.  But the behavior is still based on the design of compatibility with the old standard.  Since so many people are attached to using rodents, improving experiences keyboard buffers has not been widely viewed as a very critical priority.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but my two cents:

First off, I'd advise writing everything as a script file wherever possible and just running `php <filename>`, but I realise that's not the point of the question.

If I do just want to test something reeeally quick (let's say I've forgotten if `array_flip` returns a flipped array, or does it flip the original?) then I use the `-r` flag:

```
C:\PHP>php -r "$arr = array(5,6,7); $arr2 = array_flip($arr); print_r($arr); print_r($arr2);"
```

You can backspace all you want as you're still in the command shell, not the PHP shell.

(Also you can save yourself precious tenths of seconds by just typing `php` instead of `php.exe`)